# how to implement an abstract class with static properties in typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, typedi

I am creating a job system and I want my DSL to look like the following:

```js
@ScheduledTaskProcessor()
export class ScoringProcessor extends AbstractScheduledProcessor<ScoringInput> {

  static cron = CRON_NIGHTLY_FIRST_BATCH

  async process(args: ScoringInput) {
     // does some work
  }
}
```

i would love AbstractScheduledProcessor to look like the following:

```js
export abstract class AbstractScheduledProcessor<T> {

  abstract static cron: string;

  abstract process(args: T): Promise<void>

  ... other non abstract method follow ...
```

but i get: TS1243: 'static' modifier cannot be used with 'abstract' modifier.

**Can anyone suggest a path forward.  Perhaps I can use my class decorator as a HOF to create the class with the static property.**

FYI my ScheduledTaskProcessor decorator function curently looks like this:

```js
import { Container } from 'typedi'


export function ScheduledTaskProcessor(): ClassDecorator {

  return function(target) {
    console.log('registering: ', target)
    Container.of('ScheduledTaskProcessor').set(target.name, target)
  }

}
```

Comment: The error explains the problem. Either make the property only abstract or only static.

Comment: As mentioned before, why not just make your cron string static and overwrite it, when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make sure that you have to set a static value with decorators. The approach would look like this:

```
// This interface represents the type of an uninstantiated class, so the class itself.
// In Javascript it's just regularly called constructor but you could also call 
// it SchedulerClass
interface SchedulerConstructor { 
  cron: string; // A member of the uninstantiated class/constructor is static.
  new (...args: any[]): any;
}

// Decorators get the class itself passed not an instantiation of it. This means interfaces
// we set here define the structure of the class and not of the object. This gives us
// the opportunity to use our constructor-interface to restrict which classes can be
// decorated and thus enforcing the static member cron.
export function ScheduledTaskProcessor(constructor: SchedulerConstructor) {
    // decorator logic
}

@ScheduledTaskProcessor // No compiler warning because the static is set.
class ScoringProcess {
    static cron = "test"
}

@ScheduledTaskProcessor // Error static cron not declared.
class ScoringProcessError {
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GDVckyJ0hDi7TGKvHCOnsMTUTygCiYJK4JA+Q7S-iCXCbba7ZK2aIGVAAD096EcmG4CQ5HC6ETqInA0gA1gAFSbixTof53dVDGbD2rhXr9OZh9Bw0DDfTjcZGXNJAnJCRMe24NEYgACa9H49g09nTvnKzAADklFENsRoA3UAfhBE5q12XBsE8VVazeBtbRlAxdXgKokirGcmDnfdDyPV56wmTkAF5QAAIjQPgSNvfQH2qEdwjHScMLnJ4jAAUXQSZkjw94CI4I0FVxAIIiQ65KjxdC3xkdjOOw1EgA)

Comment: amazing!  super well done Mirco S!  thanks for heping ot and welcome to SO